# How to edit online document in local editor?

Tags: c#, angularjs, server, editor, local

I need to edit online document in my local editor (Eg; LibreOffice).

I have a document repository and I have to add this new functionality to edit documents in the local editor. When the user saves the document, it is uploaded to the server.

Do you know any way to do it?

Comment: Any idea? Help me, please

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I created an ActiveX control in c#. Users install the component on their computer and can now use it.